# Group By "Users" in power apps

Tags: group-by, count, distinct, powerapps-canvas

How do I group by 'Created By' in power apps? I want to get a distinct count of the users and how many records each individual user submitted.
I keep getting an error when I try to group by that column. I am using sharepoint and I do not have any numerical data in my list.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the GroupBy() function expects the name of a primitive column.
Perhaps you could use a virtual column to work around this obstacle:

```
GroupBy(AddColumns('YourDataSource',"CrByEmail",'Created By'.Email),"CrByEmail")
```